# NullInjectorError - Root standalone component does not import HttpClientModule properly

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-standalone-components

I have an issue, I want to rewrite my app code and change main module to main root standalone component pointed in main.ts.

All works fine but I have an issue with HttpClientModule. I am using HttpClient in one  of services which is provided in root. In MainComponent i added HttpClientModules to imports array but then error occurs which is saying I didn't provided HttpClientMoudle  to app and this service can't use it.

```
Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[MainComponent])[MainService -> MainService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

When I added this HttpClientModule to AppRoutingModule which I also added to main.ts as

```
bootstrapApplication(MainComponent, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(RoutingModule)],
});
```

it works fine, service has no any problem.

Here is a code with basic example of this problem, could someone explain me why import to root standalone component doesn't work in this case but import to RoutngModule is solves the problem?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhpbvm?file=src/main.ts

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Problem solved. In this case, I have to add `provideHttpClient()`to providers array in bootstrapApplication() function in main.ts file.

```
import { provideHttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(AppRoutingModule),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find it? Should be a BIG Notice from Angular, because it breaks everything

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup) might be helpful:

```
boostrapApplication(App, {providers: [
  provideHttpClient(),
]});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem as follows

```
import { provideHttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
}).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err)
);
```

In this way, you explicitly provide the providers provideRouter(routes) and provideHttpClient() to the application. These providers can be used to configure specific features of the application, such as configuring routing and initialising a custom HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use this:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations(), provideHttpClient()]
};
```